# Pixel issue of characters in concatenation. Cols should be fixed as per the width for all the cols concatenated

Tags: sql, oracle, rtf

These values are stored as part of 1 column. They are actually 3 cols concatenated through sql oracle. How can I make these values look aligned as 3 different cols?

Currently, these numbers will be 3 characters for 1 col, 10 for second and 7 for 3rd col. For some reason I had to bring them in 1 column to use in my rtf template. I need a solution in SQL Oracle to set width in concatenated cols. I am using cast here but this is the output I am getting

```
CAST(TO_CHAR(G_WEIGHTAGE)||'%' as char(3))||'  '
||CAST(TO_CHAR(G_ACHIEVE , '990.00')||'%' as char(13)) ||'  '
||CAST( TO_CHAR(ROUND((G_ACHIEVE_FACTOR*(G_WEIGHTAGE/100)),2)*(TARGET_BONUS/100), '990.00')||'%' as char(8)) AS G_WAIT
```

This is for 1st line in this output. I have written for other lines as well same way.

This is how it is coming

```
 40% 96.79% 9.60%
 10% 99.89% 2.70%
20% NA/ 51.42% 0.00%
 10% 62.90% 0.00%
10% 112.77% 4.80%
```

Output I need :

```
 40%     96.79%     9.60%
 10%     99.89%     2.70%
 20%  NA/51.42%     0.00%
 10%     62.90%     0.00%
 10%    112.77%     4.80%
```

I believe this is due to different characters having different width. Like N has different width in comparison to 1.

Comment: Enter your data as `formatted text` please.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your SQL. Also text is better than images. I think you probably just want `RPAD()`, maybe with `SUBSTR()`. But a clear question will get you a clear answer.

Comment: Normally you would use lpad/rpad, but casting as `char` should work as well (it should be equivalent to `rpad`). Can you post a complete test case so I can see which step isn't working as expected?

Comment: I tried everything but it seems it is due to length of Sach character like N is big and 1 is small and 
1 space charcuterie is if different length . This is pixel length due to which it looks tilted. If I use 0 instead of space it comes fine.

Comment: I don't think you mean "Pixel" (or "charcuterie"). Are you talking about aligning with variable-width fonts?

Comment: Yes variable width fonts of characters I mean...as N is big in comparison to space in terms of width... thus seems to be pixel issue

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you want a [PAD](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions082.htm) function. They add spaces to make a string a specific width. Try this:

```
lpad(TO_CHAR(G_WEIGHTAGE)||'%',3) ||'  '
||lpad(TO_CHAR(G_ACHIEVE , '990.00')||'%',13) ||'  '
||lpad(TO_CHAR(ROUND((G_ACHIEVE_FACTOR*(G_WEIGHTAGE/100)),9)*(TARGET_BONUS/100), '990.00')||'%',7) AS G_WAIT
```

Comment: Hey I have applied lpad but the problem is this is adding spaces but still not making the values right aligned . Actually its gets aligned but the length of second col data makes the first col data move a bit more towards left like in 3rd row and 5th row as the length of second col data is different here.

Comment: @AlkaOjha you might need more padding - I'll edit my answer to increase the values

Comment: No I tried everything but it seems it is due to length of Sach character like N is big and 1 is small and 
1 space charcuterie is if different length . This is pixel length due to which it looks tilted. If I use 0 instead of space it comes fine.

Comment: There is more than just SQL involved. While SQL can adjust the number of characters in the resulting columns, it cannot adjust for character width differences.  What tool are you using the display the results. Perhaps changing the FONT to a fixed or mono spaced font.

Comment: Hey ...I am using rtf template to display my output here ... RTF is created on word document with tags to generate the output.... I am using SQL in bi publisher tool which calls rtf template and prints the output as per the rtf layout. Plz help where sql or rtf how to make fixed or mono spaced font...

Comment: Also do confirm if whitespace or blank will also work with monospace font as I am gonna append lpad with blank in my sql query or do suggest if there is any other way to do it ?